# difficult integral involving arcsin(x)

Tags: integration, contour-integration

I have a difficult integral to compute.  I know the result by guessing the answer, but need to know the method of calculation.  The integral is

$$
\int_{a}^{b}{\rm d}p\,{p \over p^{2} - 2\mu}\,
\left[{2\arcsin\left({1 \over p}\,{p^{2} - ba \over  b-a}\right) - \pi}\right]
=\pi\ln\left({2\mu - a^{2} \over 
\mu - {ba \over 2} + \frac{1}{2}
\sqrt{\,\left(2\mu - a^{2}\right)\left(2\mu - b^{2}\,\right)\,}}\right)
$$

I am considering the case where $a<b$, $a^2<2\mu$, and $b^2<2\mu$, so that there is no divergence from the denominator.  I suspect it can be solved from some contour integral trick, especially since, by using the properties of arcsin, I can rewrite it in the following form:

$
{\rm Re} \int_{a}^{b} dp\, \frac{p}{p^2-2\mu} \Big[-2i \ln \big( \frac{1}{2} i (p^2 -ab) +\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{(p^2 - a^2) (b^2 - p^2) }\big)-\pi\Big]
 =
 \pi \ln \frac{ (2\mu - a^2)}
{\mu-\frac{1}{2}ba + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(2\mu - a^2)(2\mu-b^2)}}$,

where the Re takes the real part.  With this form, I am pretty sure there is a contour integral trick since the log function on the left is so similar to the log function on the right.  Unfortunately I cannot seem to figure it out, although I can verify it numerically.   Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks, Dan